# What is the best way to open a SharePoint document on a web site that must use CSOM?

Tags: csom, asp.net, web

I have a website that is NOT a SharePoint server.

I need to display on my website a document that IS stored in SharePoint.

So I will have to access the document via CSOM, but what is the best technique for showing such a document (read-only) on my website?

Comment: What do you mean by "show"? What's the type of the document? Word? PDF? Image? Isn't a simple link enough?

Comment: By 'show' I mean either open or display in a frame. And my SharePoint server is inside the firewall, but my webserver is public-facing